# Allow Previewer Role to Preview Posts

Tags: previews

When I'm finished with a blog post, I would like to publish it ONLY to a select set of reviewers so they have the opportunity to fact-check the article or suggest edits before it's made available to the general public.

I can't give my previewers access to Draft posts, because I may have many posts in draft status that are not yet ready for preview.

What's the best way to do that?

My current thought is to create a new role, 'Previewers,' and a new post category, 'Preview,' and in the loop, only show posts with the 'preview' category if the user is in the 'preview' role. This seems like it should be straightforward to implement. (This coming from someone who only knows enough about Wordpress programming to be dangerous, though.)

Is that the best solution? Is it a good solution? Is it a workable solution? Is there a 'better' solution that you'd use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party free WordPress plugin 'Public Post Preview' which generates a unique 'Preview Link' for draft posts. You can share this link to anyone to preview post.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/public-post-preview/

[image]

You will only find option to create unique public preview link once you save post as draft.

Hope this helps..!!